# Automatic Email Send in Microsoft Bot Framework Composer

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am developing chatbot using **Microsoft bot framework composer**. I added this chatbot to **Microsoft Teams** channel as well. It is a IT Help desk chatbot. We have a separate ticketing system, whenever user send a email to **support@abc.com**, the support ticket would be automatically created.

**I want my chatbot to send a email automatically to create a ticket when the user needs to create a ticket using chatbot.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do that. For example, you can use "Send an HTTP request" action in the composer, and call an endpoint where you do this email processing (for example: you can quickly test by using a logic app which will be your http endpoint, and inside this logic app use an email connector - outlook or other)

More details on the "send an http request" step [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-send-http-request?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#add-a-send-an-http-request-action)

And a tutorial to send an email with Logic Apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#create-the-logic-app)